# My Game has a memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am working on a simple game. I was monitoring the heap size and it was slowly increasing to the Max limit of 48mb. However, I don't see anything in my code that would cause such high memory usage. All I am doing is drawing nine circles on the screen and setting a shadow around them. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
 public void run() {
    Log.d("Speed Buttons", "Background thread has started");
    //standard game loop
    Canvas canvas;
    while(isRunning == true)
    {



        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            continue;
        }

        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        //call dodraw method
        doDraw(canvas);


        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    }


}


protected void doDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint circle = new Paint();
    circle.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    //creates a glow around the circles
    circle.setShadowLayer(5,0,0,Color.RED);

    op.setWidthSetHeight(getWidth(), getHeight());
    int big = 130;
    op.setBig(130);


    //I have to use getwidth and getheight in draw, because in context, it would include the title bar and status bar
    //circle 5
    //using convertDP to pixel for everything

    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2,op.convertDpToPixel(6000),circle);

    //circle 2
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2-big*scale,op.convertDpToPixel(6000),circle);
    //circle 1
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2-(big*scale),getHeight()/2-big*scale,op.convertDpToPixel(6000),circle);
    //circle 3
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2+ (big*scale),getHeight()/2-big*scale,op.convertDpToPixel(6000),circle);
    //circle 8
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2+big*scale,op.convertDpToPixel(6000),circle);
    //circle 4
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2-(big*scale),getHeight()/2,op.convertDpToPixel(6000),circle);
    //circle 6
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2+(big*scale),getHeight()/2,op.convertDpToPixel(6000),circle);
    //circle 7
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2-(big*scale),getHeight() / 2 + big * scale, op.convertDpToPixel(6000), circle);
    //circle 9
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2+(big*scale),getHeight()/2+big*scale,op.convertDpToPixel(6000),circle);










}
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Answer (score 1):

It's possible all those calls to drawCircle are creating local variables in the heap.  The garbage collector should take care of them, which is why it's capping off.  Are you having any problems? Or is it just a concern?

Comment: If this is the problem, can you provide a solution? As it stands, this would be more useful as a comment.

Comment: For starters, it seems moving the instantiation of `circle` out of the draw loop would help.

Comment: No, it's more than a concern. I watched the free heap space dip from 30MB to 2MB in a period of 10 minutes. I'm not sure what would have happened if I let it get down to zero. I stopped it before then. I'm guessing an out of memory exception..

Comment: You could try it and see if the garbage collector runs

Answer (score 0):

http://www.curious-creature.com/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/comment-page-1/ has some interesting background on what, how and how to avoid memory leaks in Android.